# How can I create and update a dict simultaneously?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I see a tonne of answers on how to update an existing `dict` if a key doesn't exist, but my question is different. How can I update a dictionary but create the *dictionary* if it doesn't exist?

Use case - single cell of Jupyter notebook:

```py
my_dict |= function_return_dict
```

I want to do something like the above without doing:

```py
my_dict = {}
my_dict |= function_return_dict(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

so that I can run all in the notebook and/or update `my_dict` on multiple successive runs (with different function args).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how you would use the bitwise opertor  (which corresponds to an update operation) on a dictionary that does not exist.

I would write what you desire using a function that creates a empty dictionary if it is not given as an argument.

```py
# The following funtion update a empty dict by default, 
# or a specific dict when specified (orig argument)
f = lambda d, orig={}: orig | d

mydict = f({1: "one"})

print(mydict)

mydict = f({3: "three"}, mydict)

print(mydict)
```

To be able to not specify the variable, you can use a try catch to check if the variable exists. The suggested function can be written as:

```py
def f(d):
    try:
        out = mydict | d
    except NameError:
        out = {} | d
    return out
```

but this suppose that mydict should be treated as a global variable in your code. I believe this is possible in python notebooks natively.

In your specific case, you can call you function that returns a dict inside the simple function I suggested:

```py
mydict = f(function_that_returns_a_dict(args, ...))
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing, thank you so much! I never even thought to supply an optional arg to a lambda..! Can I add one thing - what happens (I'd like an update) when I make a second call? Thank you, thank you!

Comment: The same thing happens again :). In both suggestions, f() returns a dict and if you want  `mydict` updated, you will need to put the output of the f function in mydict again: `mydict = f(...)`

Comment: Yes I see, thank you. I'd prefer the first solution, except that it requires a different line when called the second time. Perhaps I should just check whether `mydict` is in globals or not first - that could've saved me a question! :(